# Substring of a particular string using char* in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I would like to write a function which returns substring of a string.

```
f(what string, from which index, how many chars)
```

I have done it but using string class, but i would like to use char*, but I don't know how. Could you please correct the code so it uses char* not string*? It is confusing in c++.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
//index - starting at, n- how many chars
string* subString(string s, int index, int n){
    string* newString = new string("");
    for(int i = index; i < s.length() && i < n + index; i++)
        *newString += s.at(i);
    return newString;
}


int main()
{   string s1 = "Alice has a cat";
    string* output = subString(s1, 2, 4);
    cout<<(*output)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I have done it but using `string` class, but i would like to use `char*`*. And why is that?

Comment: From what I can see, you're still using string. Actually, string*, which is worse than char*. Why do you need pointers & dynamic allocation. I suggest you read a good C++ book first.

Comment: if you don't want to use string, and want to use char *, use char * throughout. Preferably char const *. You have ended up with a confusing mess, doing this.

Comment: Note that `std::string` already has a [`substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

//index - starting at, n- how many chars
char* subString(char *s, int index, int n){
    char *res = new char[n + 1];
    sprintf(res, "%.*s", n, s + index);
    return res;
}


int main()
{   
    char* s1 = "Alice has a cat";
    char* output = subString(s1, 2, 4);
    cout << output << endl;
    system("pause");
    delete[] output;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another way is `memcpy(res, s + index, n); res[n] = 0;` instead of `sprintf(...);`

Comment: Using `sprintf` is a very inefficient way of doing this. (It has to parse the format string "%.*s" and parsing is always expensive.) Better to use `memcpy` or `strncpy` as suggested by ognev.p

Answer (score 1):

I can correct it to use `string` not `string*`:

```
string output(s1, 2, 4);
```

or if you want a function to your specification:

```
string subString(string s, int index, int n) {
    return s.substr(index, n);
}
```

Using `char*` would be more awkward, since you'll need to manually allocate and free buffers to keep the strings in. I suggest you don't do that.

Comment: The reason to use `char *` might be that the result is to be sent to a function with a `const char *` parameter. In that case you can use the `std::string::c_str()` member function.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
char *subString(const char *s, int index, int n) {
    char *res = (char*)malloc(n + 1);
    if (res) {
        strncpy(res, s + index, n + 1);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be strncpy(res, s + index, n); res[n] = '\0'; ?

Comment: @user763305 - `strncpy` fills with 0's.

Comment: `strncpy` fills with 0's _if_ it reaches the end of the source string during the copying.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you do it. (Haven't tested). This returns null on failure but you can easily modify it to use exceptions instead.

```
char* subString(string s, int index, int n){
    if (s.length() < (n+index)) {return null;}
    char* newString = new (nothrow) char[n+1];
    if (newString){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {newString[i] = s.at(i + index);}
        newString[n] = '\0';
    }        
    return newString;
}
```